# Nextjs 13 Supbase auth redirect post social login not working properly

Tags: supabase, next.js13, supabase-js

I am having some trouble getting Supabase auth working properly in NextJS 13. I would like some pages to be protected and if the user navigates to those pages, they should first be redirected to the login page where they will need to login and then they should be automatically redirected back to the original page.

Here is my middleware file that enforces the redirect to login page:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(req) {
    const res = NextResponse.next();
    const supabase = createMiddlewareClient({ req, res });

    const { data: session } = await supabase.auth.getSession();

    // Check auth condition
    if (session?.session?.user?.email) {
        // Authentication successful, forward request to protected route.
        return res;
    }

    // Auth condition not met, redirect to login page
    const redirectUrl = req.nextUrl.clone();
    redirectUrl.pathname = "/login";
    redirectUrl.searchParams.set(`redirectedFrom`, req.nextUrl.pathname);
    return NextResponse.redirect(redirectUrl);
}

export const config = {
    matcher: ["/protected-page"],
};
```

This redirects to the login page with the url set to
`http://localhost:3000/login?redirectedFrom=%2Fprotected-page`

The login page looks like this:

```
import { createClientComponentClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";
import { Auth } from "@supabase/auth-ui-react";
import { ThemeSupa } from "@supabase/auth-ui-shared";
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

export default function Login({}) {
    const searchParams = useSearchParams();
    const redirectedFrom = searchParams.get("redirectedFrom");

    const redirectURL = () => {
        let url =
            process?.env?.NEXT_PUBLIC_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URL ?? // Manually set in vercel (mainly for staging)
            process?.env?.NEXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL ?? // This points to prod url
            "http://localhost:3000"; // local
        // Make sure to include `https://` when not localhost.
        url = url.includes("http") ? url : `https://${url}`;
        // Make sure to including trailing `/`.
        // url = url.charAt(url.length - 1) === "/" ? url : `${url}/`;
        // if redirect query is provided, add that too
        if (redirectedFrom) {
            url = `${url}${encodeURI(redirectedFrom)}`;
        }
        return url;
    };

    const supabase = createClientComponentClient();

    return (
        <>
            <div className="container mx-auto p-6">
                <div className="flex items-start justify-center">
                    <div className="w-96 rounded-lg p-6 shadow-lg md:mt-10">
                        <Auth
                            supabaseClient={supabase}
                            appearance={{
                                theme: ThemeSupa,
                            }}
                            providers={["google"]}
                            redirectTo={redirectURL()}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Upon logging using the Google Login, I see the browser navigating to `http://localhost:3000/login?code=1139985f-2b7f-4107-994d-e0a157633182&redirectedFrom=%2Fregister`

but then it redirects back to the `http://localhost:3000/login?redirectedFrom=%2Fregister` page while being logged in.

It seems when the request goes through the middlware even after being logged in, the session isnt there so the middleware routes back to login page, but by that time the user is in fact logged in successfully.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Please read the docs on the latest auth-helpers as it talks about you implementing a code exchange route due to the Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE) auth flow which allows you to do server side sign in as you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the prefabricated router from supabase the redirect request should go to /auth/callback, so supabase can handle the authorization code.

Just add the corrent redirect url to your signInWithOAuth() function call, like this:

```js
let { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
      provider: 'google',
      options: {
        redirectTo: window.location.origin + "/auth/callback"
      }
})
```